# how can i give the order by in s3 database

Tags: php, database, amazon-simpledb

```
if(!$_GET){
    echo "{'success':false, 'error':'No query parameters submitted'}";
    return;
}

// 1. Include the SimpleDB class if it does not exist
if (!class_exists('SimpleDB'))require_once('sdb.php');  

// 2. Set awsAccessKey and awsSecretKey to your values
require_once('config.inc.php');  

// create connection
$sdb = new SimpleDB(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);  
$condition = "";
$status = "";

//$params = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['hash']));
$params = $_GET;
foreach($params as $key => $value){
    $condition .= " " . $key . " = '" . $value . "' and" ;      
}

$condition = preg_replace('/and$/', "", $condition);

$query = "select * from $domain";

if($condition!= " _empty_ = '' "){
    $query .= " where $condition ";
}

$fileHash = '{';
if($files = $sdb->select($domain, $query)){
    $status = 'true';
    $fileHash .= "'files' : ".json_encode($files).", ";
}else{
    $status = 'false';
    $fileHash .= "'files' : [], ";
    $fileHash .= "'error' : 'No records retrieved from SimpleDB ".json_encode($sdb->ErrorCode)."', ";
}
$fileHash .= "'success':".$status."}";
echo $fileHash;
```

**my json response** 
    {
        'files': [{
            "Name": "4cf0dadfddfe6",
            "Attributes": {
                "title": "Earrings!",
                "file_size": "135023",
                "url": "http:\/\/dtzhqpwfdzscm.cloudfront.net\/4cf0dadfddfe6.jpg",
                "file_name": "4cf0dadfddfe6.jpg",
                "time_stamp": "1290853092",
                "file_type": "image\/jpeg",
                "content_obj_type": "upload",
                "thumb": "http:\/\/dtzhqpwfdzscm.cloudfront.net\/4cf0dadfde32b.jpg",
                "width": "176.04166666666669",
                "height": "171",
                "userid": "4",
                "gibid": "54",
                "contentid": "4cf0dadfddfe6",
                "qqfile": "il_570xN.182320055.jpg",
                "original_name": "il_570xN.182320055.jpg",
                "y": "72",
                "x": "535",
                "on_floor": "false",
                "success": "true",
                "gibview": "O",
                "avatar_url": "",
                "crop_url": ""
            }
        }],
        'success': true
    }

i want to sort by time_stamp how can i do this .? or any good article for learning s3 database please suggest.

Comment: Amazon S3? May be you meant SimpleDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that with SimpleDB you can only ORDER BY an attribute that you used in the WHERE clause.  That's why

```
select * from second where gibid = '54' and gibview = 'O' order by time_stamp
```

doesn't work.  Adding "time_stamp is not null" to the WHERE clause makes time_stamp available for ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

Like in any other sql dialect - sorting can be performed with `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY time_stamp
```

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?UsingSelect.html

Comment: : 'No records retrieved from SimpleDB "InvalidSortExpression this error is coming , what is the problem ?

Comment: @Rahul Mehta: how could i say if i don't see query?

Comment: select * from second where gibid = '54' and gibview = 'O' order by time_stamp, this is the query

Comment: @Rahul Mehta: is there a `time_stamp` field in the table?

Comment: @zerkms as i am new to amazon simple db how can i check that there is field time_stamp in the table

Comment: @Rahul Mehta: to be clear - I don't know ;-) I just googled it for your question and read several pages in documentation ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Amazon db has null values so by giving `time_stamp is not null` condition have solved the problem.